# Mock object leak

Tags: googlemock

I am trying to use googlemock in the following way([Class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLgRj.png)) for my project : https://github.com/aniket11bh/TurtleMock

So, basically I am using a proxy class (which is singleton) to decide whether to use mock objects or the actual ones. I'm [injecting](https://github.com/aniket11bh/TurtleMock/blob/master/unitTest/Source.cpp#L22) the mock object in to the proxy class whenever a test is running.

**Also I want to mention that I've explicitly mentioned the constructor and destructor of the mock class in [MockService.h](https://github.com/aniket11bh/TurtleMock/blob/master/MockService/MockService.h) and in corresponding [MockService.cpp](https://github.com/aniket11bh/TurtleMock/blob/master/MockService/MockService.cpp) file.**

Now,

- I've already declared the destructor of the interface class [IService.h](https://github.com/aniket11bh/TurtleMock/blob/master/Service/IService.h) as virtual.
- The [mock](https://github.com/aniket11bh/TurtleMock/blob/master/unitTest/Source.cpp#L21) object is created on stack.
- And the test is passing.
- Have also checked with `Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(&mockService);` is returning 1.
- I've also tried creating mock Object on heap and then deleting it, but still no luck.

  ```
  TEST(ServiceTest, ServiceTest_1) 
  {
    MockService* mockService = new MockService();
    ServiceProxy::SetMockObject(mockService);

    EXPECT_CALL(*mockService, Walk(_)).WillOnce(Return(true));

    TurtleTest t;
    t.Walk("forward");

    ServiceProxy::SetMockObject(nullptr);
    bool result = Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(mockService);

    std::cout << " Result : " << result << std::endl;
    delete mockService; 
  }
  ```
- I've checked the program in debug mode. So, whenever TEST ends, `~MockService()` gets called, and it finally calls `void Mock::UnregisterLocked(internal::UntypedFunctionMockerBase* mocker)` from `gmock-spec-builder.cc` where it unregisters the mock objects from the states.

Even after taking care of these things, on running the unit test it is showing mock object leak as :

> Source.cpp(24): ERROR: this mock object (used in test
>   ServiceTest.ServiceTest_1) should be deleted but never is. Its address
>   is @000000000031F4A0. ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program
>   exit. Expectations on a mock object is verified when the object is
>   destructed. Leaking a mock means that its expectations aren't
>   verified, which is usually a test bug. If you really intend to leak a
>   mock, you can suppress this error using
>   testing::Mock::AllowLeak(mock_object), or you may use a fake or stub
>   instead of a mock.

I know that it can be taken care by using `Mock::AllowLeak(&mockService);` But I don't understand why this is happening at all in the first place ? Can someone help me out in this case !

Comment: Which version of google test do you use ?

Comment: what about lib files, like https://github.com/aniket11bh/TurtleMock/blob/master/googletest/googlemock.lib, are they up to date, compiled for you project options? Please recompile - or even add gtest source to your project and compile if necessary

Comment: @PiotrNycz I compiled them using cmake as given on googlemock github website which downloads the current version of googlemock everytime and works on the master branch.

Comment: @Hugoy I have done that around 20 days ago, so I guess I might be able to provide the commit of that day in some time.

Comment: Anyways, I got it working. But I still don't have any idea of why this was not working !
Basically, I was creating a (library) dll for the mock object. (.cpp with only constructors and destructors). When I moved that to the test library with header files only. It is working perfectly fine without any mock object leak.

Comment: It seems mock object cannot be exported.. I spend several days before your question and answer saved me.